# I am having trouble getting my window.onload to work with navLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So here is my code for my navlink and inside the addingredients, I have it load onload to fetch something from the backend. However it is not loading onload when I move among the navLink but it will work when I reload the page. Is there a way to run this function to fetch the data when the user go to the page? I just need a way to make that so when the user press the link to go onto /addingingredients pages, that the window.onload will trigger a script. If there are any other way to do this that be great

```
<NavLink
          to="/addingredients"
          className="links"
          activestyle
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
          Add Ingredients
        </NavLink>
```

```
  window.onload = async function() {
try {
          const response = await fetch("/todos");
          const jsonData = await response.json();
...
}
```

Comment: You question is unclear and you've not provided a [mcve] to provide any context for what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to run an effect in the target routed component when it mounts? If so, then use the `useEffect` hook for this (*or `componentDidMount` in the case it is a class-based component*). If this isn't the case for what you are trying to do then please update your post to clarify what you are asking for help with and what any issues are.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `window.onload` will likely have been called prior to your React app having been mounted. This seems like an XY-problem. What are you really trying to accomplish overall?